# Find out deselected item in spark list with multiple selection

Tags: list, apache-flex, selection, multi-select, flex-spark

In a spark list I could use the `change` event to find out which item has been selected or deselected.
The dispatched `IndexChangeEvent` object has the properties `newIndex` and `oldIndex` holding this information.

But with multiple selection allowed this doesn't work anymore because `newIndex` and `oldIndex` could refer to indices of still selected elements.

A solution would be to copy the `selectedIndices` vector to another variable and compare this variable with `selectedIndices` after a change in selection, but this seems to be somewhat complex.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way two get the index/item a user is **deselecting** while other elements are still selected?

Comment: IndexChangeEvent is not a documented event on the Spark list, using change or changing is probably better.  That said, I Don't have an easy solution for you. I'd have expected w/ allowMultipleSelection activated that newIndex and oldIndex would contain the selectedIndices arrays.  File a enhancement request at bugs.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the selectedIndicies and compare the difference.

```
private static function findMissing(ar1:Array, ar2:Array):Array
{
    var missing:Array = [];
    for each(var item:Object in ar1)
    {
        if(ar2.indexOf(item) < 0)
            missing.push(item);
    }

    return missing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also extend your custom data object with

- a bindable boolean property:
  `_selected`, which gets updated via the list interactions.
- and an event that can be fired from
  it: `selectionChanged`.

In the `selected` setter - if it actually changed - you can fire your own bubbling `selectionChanged` event, and capture it wherever you need.

**SelectableItem.as** - the custom data structure representing a row data of the list

```
[Bindable]
[Event(name="selectionChanged",type="flash.events.Event")]
public class SelectableItem
{
    public static const EVENT_SELECTION_CHANGED:String = 'selectionChanged';
    private var _selected:Boolean;
    private var _name:String;

    public function SelectableItem()
    {
    }

    public function get selected():Boolean
    {
        return _selected;
    }

    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void
    {
        if (_selected != value)
        {
            _selected = value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_SELECTION_CHANGED, true));
        }
    }

    public function get name():String
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public function set name(value:String):void
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

**MyDataGrid.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:DataGrid xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    allowMultipleSelection="true">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;

            protected override function updateRendererDisplayList(r:IListItemRenderer):void
            {
                super.updateRendererDisplayList(r);
                if (r && r.data)
                    r.data.selected = DataGrid(r.owner).isItemSelected(r.data);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

**TestApplication.mxml**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var item:SelectableItem= new SelectableItem();
                item.name = 'Item ' + i;
                item.addEventListener(SelectableItem.EVENT_SELECTION_CHANGED, onItemSelectionChanged);
                list.addItem(item);
            }
        }

        private function onItemSelectionChanged(event:Event):void
        {
            trace(event);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<my:MyDataGrid dataProvider="{list}" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

I hope this helps.